# Uppercase letter using pipe in C

Tags: c, process, pipe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

static struct termios old, new;

/* Initialize new terminal i/o settings */

void initTermios(int echo) 

{

   tcgetattr(0, &old); /* grab old terminal i/o settings */

   new = old; /* make new settings same as old settings */

   new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* disable buffered i/o */

   new.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO; /* set echo mode */

   tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */

}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios(void) 
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}

/* Read 1 character - echo defines echo mode */
char getch_(int echo) 
{
  char ch;
  initTermios(echo);
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();
  return ch;
}

/* Read 1 character without echo */
char getch(void) 
{
  return getch_(0);
}

/* Read 1 character with echo */
char getche(void) 
{
  return getch_(1);
}

void INThandler(int);

void INThandler(int sig)
{
    char c;
    signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
    printf("\n Ctrl+c foi detetado, clique y para confirmar \n");
    c = getchar();
    if(c == 'y' || c == 'Y')
        exit(0);
    else
        signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
    getchar();
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
  int fd[2];

  char readbuffer[80];
  pipe(fd);
  int pid = fork();
  char ch;
  if(pid < 0)
  {
    printf("\n Erro");
    exit(1);
  }
  else if(pid == 0)
  {
    close(fd[0]);
    do
    {
        ch = getch();
        write(fd[1], &ch, sizeof(ch));
    }   while(ch != '\n');
    getchar();


  }
  else
  {
    close(fd[1]);
    while(1)
    {
        read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        char upper = toupper(readbuffer[0]);
        char down = tolower(readbuffer[0]);
        if(readbuffer[0] != upper)
        {
            printf("%c \n", upper);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c \n", down);
        }

    }

  }
  return(0);
}
```

So basically this is a task that is: Using communication between processes, convert automatically upper letters to small letters, and small letters to upper letters, without them appearing in input. Basically I don't see my input just the output. And when CTRL+C is hit, the program should recognize it and ask for a confirmation by asking the user to type "y".
My program runs, but when I remove the \n from "printf("%c \n", upper);" and from "printf("%c \n", down);" the program starts acting weird... When I remove it I have to hit enter to see the output, but with it it appears automatically just like I wanted... Can someone explain me why?

I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` doesn't actually print to stdout immediately -- it just puts characters into an output buffer to be flushed to stdout at some later point.  That "later point" is generally whenever a newline is printed if the output is a terminal, but you can change that with setbuf:

```
setbuf(stdout, 0);  // set stdout to unbuffered
```

after which *every* call to printf will immediately flush the buffer.  Alternately, you can use `fflush(stdout)` to flush the buffer at any specific point in your program.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, setbuf(stdout, 0); solved it